# Bot Framework FormFlow in Cortana is not accepting input for String fields

Tags: .net, botframework, formflow

I have a Formflow which is working for the fields taking input from displayed enum options, but when it gets to a String it displays the question but Cortana does not display an area to type the answer not does the microphone icon do anything when clicked.
My formbuilder is not doing anything with this field, it is just covered under the AddRemainingFields() line.
I have tried adding the field manually in the formbuilder and setting the .SetType(typeof(string)) but this did not help.
Is there a known bug here or am I missing some code to enable the typing or microphone to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some more code?  CSK allows you to give hints about conversation state (input hints) in dialogs, and the adaptive cards do support text input.  (Not sure if this is helpful but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-input-hints?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: `when it gets to a String it displays the question but Cortana does not display an area to type the answer not does the microphone icon do anything when clicked.` I do a test with my FormFlow bot in Cortana channel, which enable me to type the text for a string field. Please share the implementation/code of your FormFlow bot so that we can reproduce the issue based on your code.